# Diferença entre "Object(meuobjeto)" e "(meuobjeto as Object)"?

Tags: actionscript-3, operadores, cast

Queria saber a diferença entre usar `Object(meuobjeto)` e `(meuobjeto as Object)` com base no código abaixo:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //Um objeto MovieClip

trace(mc as String); //null
trace(mc as MovieClip); //[object MovieClip]
trace(mc as Number); //null

trace(String(mc)); //[object MovieClip]
trace(MovieClip(mc)); //[object MovieClip]
trace(Number(mc)); //NaN
```

Sempre utilizo o operador `as`, porém, unicamente para mostrar o intellisense com as funções do meu objeto e tornar a escrita do código um pouco mais fácil. Mas afinal, qual a diferença entre os dois? É correto eu utilizá-lo dessa forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diferença entre as duas formas de realizar o `cast` está no resultado quando a operação falha:

- Usando [`as`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#as)

  ```
  trace(mc as MovieClip);
  ```

  Vai atribuir `null` nos casos em que a conversão falha.
- Envolvido em `Type()`

  ```
  trace(MovieClip(mc));
  ```

  Vai gerar um [`TypeError`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/TypeError.html) se a conversão falhar.

Pessoalmente, a primeira opção via `as` é preferível porque sempre temos `null` para lidar com...

---

<sup>Adaptação para Português da [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9660323/352449) dada no SOEN pelo utilizador @Marty.</sup>